# AlarmManager not working after change Timezone

Tags: android, timezone, alarm

```
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    long startUpTime = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > startUpTime) {
        startUpTime = startUpTime + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 222, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startUpTime, pendingIntent);


<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here is my snippet code i set alarm and mu manifest file entry about time receiver. when i change timezone from devide then alarm not working, is there any solution.

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235666/alarmmanager-not-adding-new-alarms-or-not-triggering-receiver/7236297#7236297
Look here.

Comment: i already use in my code AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP